# Steganography in C

Tags: c, image-processing, pixel, steganography, ppm

Trying to do basic Steganography on a PPM Image.

I have the basic algorithm completed. Read in the file, check the header starts with P6, get the image width and height, and the pixel data.

I need to have a total of four methods: ReadPPM, WritePPM, WriteMsg and ReadMsg.

I have the ReadImg and WriteImg methods down, but where I am stuck is with my WriteMsg method. This is basic steganography that just writes each bit of the string to the last bit in each byte. The first 8 bytes are suppose to contain the size of the string being hidden, then each byte after that starts the hidden message.

My idea was to create a massive array that holds the binary code for the size of the string, then the binary code of the string itself. I'm just trying to figure out how I would take that array and add it to each byte in the image.

Any help is much appreciated. Here is my current code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
     unsigned char red,green,blue;
} PPMPixel;

typedef struct {
     int x, y;
     PPMPixel *data;
} PPMImage;

#define CREATOR "RPFELGUEIRAS"
#define RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR 255

static PPMImage *readPPM(const char *filename)
{
    char buff[16];
    PPMImage *img;
    FILE *fp;
    int c, rgb_comp_color;
    //open PPM file for reading
    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fp) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file '%s'\n", filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    //read image format
    if (!fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp)) {
         perror(filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    //check the image format
    if (buff[0] != 'P' || buff[1] != '6') {
         fprintf(stderr, "Invalid image format (must be 'P6')\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    //alloc memory form image
    img = (PPMImage *)malloc(sizeof(PPMImage));
    if (!img) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    //check for comments
    c = getc(fp);
    while (c == '#') {
    while (getc(fp) != '\n') ;
         c = getc(fp);
    }

    ungetc(c, fp);
    //read image size information
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &img->x, &img->y) != 2) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Invalid image size (error loading '%s')\n", filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    //read rgb component
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &rgb_comp_color) != 1) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Invalid rgb component (error loading '%s')\n", filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    //check rgb component depth
    if (rgb_comp_color!= RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR) {
         fprintf(stderr, "'%s' does not have 8-bits components\n", filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    while (fgetc(fp) != '\n') ;
    //memory allocation for pixel data
    img->data = (PPMPixel*)malloc(img->x * img->y * sizeof(PPMPixel));

    if (!img) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    //read pixel data from file
    if (fread(img->data, 3 * img->x, img->y, fp) != img->y) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Error loading image '%s'\n", filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return img;
}

void writePPM(const char *filename, PPMImage *img)
{
    FILE *fp;
    //open file for output
    fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!fp) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file '%s'\n", filename);
         exit(1);
    }

    //write the header file
    //image format
    fprintf(fp, "P6\n");

    //comments
    fprintf(fp, "# Created by %s\n",CREATOR);

    //image size
    fprintf(fp, "%d %d\n",img->x,img->y);

    // rgb component depth
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n",RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR);

    // pixel data
    fwrite(img->data, 3 * img->x, img->y, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

void writeMsg(PPMImage *img, char *s)
{   

    int i;
    int len;
    len = sizeof(s);

    if (img)
    {
         j = 0;
         for (i=0; i < img->x * img->y; i++)
         {
              while(j < 8)
              {
                   if(len & 0x80)   
                   {
                        img->data[i].red= img->data[i].red | 0x01;
                   }
                   else 
                   {
                        img->data[i].red= img->data[i].red & 0xFE;
                   }

                   len=len << 1;
                   j++;

                   if (len & 0x80)  
                   {
                        img->data[i].green= img->data[i].green | 0x01;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        img->data[i].green= img->data[i].green & 0xFE;
                   }


                   len = len << 1;
                   j++;

                   if (len & 0x80)  
                   {
                        img->data[i].blue= img->data[i].blue | 0x01;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        img->data[i].blue= img->data[i].blue & 0xFE;
                   }
                   j++;
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: The formatting of your code is mostly fine... except for the function you actually want help with! Please fix it. It's completely unreadable as it is.

Comment: You need two cycles: one by len and another by bits of every char, write data only inside second cycle like @Patashu said or in reverse order (`byte << i & 0x80`). Don't roll length variable!

Comment: `len = sizeof(s)` will return the size of a pointer. If you want the length of the string, use `strlen()`.

Answer (score 2):

To extract just a single bit from a byte, do this:

`bit(i) = byte >> i & 0x1`

This shifts the byte's bits to the right i times, and then `and`s it with 0000 0001 (such that all bits except the lowest are zeroed, and the lowest bit is 0 for 0 and 1 for 1).

You can do similar for 16 bit short, 32 bit int, 64 bit long... And even for the `char`s of a string. You can use sizeof(char) to see how many bytes are in a char.

But of course you'll have more than one char (or long or int or...) to extra bits from. To decide which element to extra a bit from:

If you want the `i`th bit and elements are `x` bits wide, then get the `i%x` bit from element `[i/x]`

Now that you have this bit, to place it inside of a byte (or int or char or...), do:

steganographybyte = originalbyte&(~0x1) + bit

What this means is, you take the number ... 0000 0001, invert its bits so it's ... 1111 1110, `and` it with the original byte so all of its bits are preserved EXCEPT the lowest, then just add your bit in.